# Striped Shadows on EEVEE

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shadows

When my camera is looking at a surface at an angle, the shadows begin to look stripped. I have tried changing shadow settings but that has not helped. The stripped shadows have also appeared when I render in EEVEE too. Is there any way I can minimize or remove these?
[image]

Comment: I have a hunch that your object might be too big.

Comment: I have tried scaling it down but it didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I updated to Blender 2.81.1, It fixed the problem. Earlier I was using 2.80.

Comment: I was answering my own question and this worked